# How to know all the users that can access a database (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, users

How to know all the users that can access a database?

Answer (score 32):

Connect to the mysql instance as an admin user (generally as root) and give the following command...

```
select user from mysql.db where db='DB_NAME';
```

Comment: I just ran this against a live MariaDB (MySQL fork) and it returned 2 blank rows.

Comment: What is your database name? you need to replace "DB_NAME" by the name of your db.

Comment: Running `select user from mysql.db` without qualification returns 2 blank rows as well.

Comment: Not sure what the differences are between MariaDB and MySQL, but that query runs as expected on a standard MySQL 5 installation.

Comment: This is only part of the answer to the OP. The mysql.user.db field can contain wildcard characters that match several databases. using your proposed query misses them. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Comment: @ChrisS This is like 6 years too late, but the blank rows are user/host pairs with no username, like ''@'localhost', where user = '', host = 'localhost'

Comment: I will verify that this works properly on mysql 5.0.45 though the effective version may be newer because of RHEL's process of back porting. My test system has mysql-5.0.45-7.el5

Comment: Somehow missed, or changed in the years since written, is that the field names are now proper-cased. At least they are for my version: 'Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.23-MariaDB' and I seem to recall they have been for a while now. So it would be `SELECT User FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='DB_NAME';`

Answer (score 16):

user79644's answer gets the users with database-level privileges but will miss users with only table-level, column-level, or procedure-level privileges.  To find all of them, use the following statements:

```
SELECT user,host FROM db WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM tables_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM columns_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM procs_priv WHERE db='name';
```

In MySQL 5.5 at least, it seems as though having column-level privileges implies that you have table-level privileges.  Having table-level privileges does not imply that you have database-level privileges.  Not sure about procedure-level privileges.

Comment: This is only part of the answer. The mysql.user.db field can contain wildcard characters that match several databases. using your proposed query misses them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Comment: Which database? I'm getting `ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected`

Comment: @user124384 What's not said in the answer is that you should be using the `mysql` database. That's where all the data used by MySQL is stored. Either give the command `USE mysql;` of add the database name to the table names, such as `FROM mysql.db` or `FROM mysql.tables_priv`

Answer (score 10):

```
# current users that access the db
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 214 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+

# who can access what at anytime and his privilege level
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

# what privileges are available
mysql> show privileges;
```

Comment: show grants shows only the grants of the current (logged in) user

Comment: as root you can also do show grants for

Answer (score 4):

You have to bear in mind, that the [MySQL `GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) for databases can contain [wildcard characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html). This has to be accounted for by using `LIKE` in the query:

```
SELECT user,host FROM db WHERE 'name' LIKE db;
SELECT user,host FROM tables_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM columns_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM procs_priv WHERE db='name';
```